# i try to use Field-Level Permission in gorm, but it does not work

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

my data struct is as follows

```
type DynamicConfig struct {
    gorm.Model
    AppName string `json:"app_name" form:"app_name"`
    Creator string `gorm:"<-:create" json:"creator" form:"creator"`
    Editor string `json:"editor" form:"editor"`
    Metadata string `json:"metadata" form:"metadata"`
}
```

My idea is that the creator cannot be changed after being created, so i use gorm:"<-:create", docs says it can allow read and create.
There is such a piece of data in the database.

```
{
      "ID": 4,
      "CreatedAt": "2021-11-30T13:05:31Z",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-12-01T06:22:02Z",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "app_name": "test3",
      "creator": "xx",
      "editor": "yy",
      "metadata": "test3"
}
```

Here is my update method:

```
func UpdateDynamicConfig(dc DynamicConfig) error {
    res, err := GetDynamicConfig(DynamicConfig{
        AppName:  dc.AppName,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }else if len(res) == 0 {
        return errors.New("app conf not exists")
    }else if len(res) != 1 {
        return errors.New("more than one config meet the criteria, please check")
    }

    config := res[0]
    
    result := DB.Model(&config).Updates(dc)
    return result.Error
}
```

I call the method like this

```
    config := model.DynamicConfig{AppName: "test3", Creator: "xxxx"}
    model.UpdateDynamicConfig(config)
```

then the creator is update to xxxx.
How can i prevent a field from being updated？
Please help me, thank you very much！

Answer (score 2):

Please use Omit it will not consider the column while updating the data in table. Please refer this [link](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html) for Omit

```
result := DB.Model(&config).Omit("creator").Updates(dc)
```

OR

For field level permission please refer this [link](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission).

You can try with this

```
Name string `gorm:"->;<-:create"` // allow read and create
```

Comment: i apply gorm:"->;<-:create", it can work now!

Comment: If this solved your issue, can you upvote my answer?

Comment: i have upvoted your answer at the first time, but it shows "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I feel so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to omit a field in the update is to use the Omit function:

```
result := DB.Model(&config).Omit("Creator").Updates(dc)
```