# Gorm field level permission is not working

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm with postgresql and trying to create a new row on a table. Here is my postgresql table columns.

[image]

id field is primary key and postgresql gives field values with a sequence.I'm trying to create a new record on this table with read permissions only because I don't want to set this on code.

When I do this like following, I can read from database but also gorm wants to set the field and postgresql throwing exeption.

```
type User struct {
    Id              int        `gorm:"column:id"`
    UUID            string     `gorm:"column:uuid"`
    FirstName       string     `gorm:"column:firstname"`
    MidName         string     `gorm:"column:midname"`
    LastName        string     `gorm:"column:lastname"`
}
```

When I use field level permission like this, it's working on create because gorm doesn't want to set this field like expected. But this time reads aren't working.

```
type User struct {
    Id              int        `gorm:"-"`
    UUID            string     `gorm:"column:uuid"`
    FirstName       string     `gorm:"column:firstname"`
    MidName         string     `gorm:"column:midname"`
    LastName        string     `gorm:"column:lastname"`
}
```

I've tried `gorm:"<-:false"` `gorm:"->"` and `gorm:"->;<-:read"` but fails.

Also tried omit with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180142/i-try-to-use-field-level-permission-in-gorm-but-it-does-not-work) `postgres.DB.Model(models.User{}).Omit("id").Create(newUser)` but still not working.

How can I achieve this? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @newbie, Just curious to know what error exactly you are getting? did you check what's the exact query is getting fired in the database by putting `Debug()`?

Comment: Heyy @AshutoshSingh, I will simulate error for you again but I was getting this when I try to save any item to database.

runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Answer (score 1):

Not the best choice but solved this issue with adding hook. Now it works as expected both read an write but still thinking about field level permissions.

```
func (u *User) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    tx.Omit("id")
    return nil
}
```